# TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < int() in Python 3

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

The below code is ordering poker hands. It works well in Python 2.7 but it does not work in Python 3. What are the changes that have been made causing it to give an TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < int()?

```
def poker(hands):
    scores = [(i, score(hand.split())) for i, hand in enumerate(hands)]
    winner = sorted(scores , key=lambda x:x[1])[-1][0]
    return hands[winner]

def score(hand):
    ranks = '23456789TJQKA'
    rcounts = {ranks.find(r): ''.join(hand).count(r) for r, _ in hand}.items()
    score, ranks = zip(*sorted((cnt, rank) for rank, cnt in rcounts)[::-1])
    if len(score) == 5:
        if ranks[0:2] == (12, 3): #adjust if 5 high straight
            ranks = (3, 2, 1, 0, -1)
        straight = ranks[0] - ranks[4] == 4
        flush = len({suit for _, suit in hand}) == 1
        '''no pair, straight, flush, or straight flush'''
        score = ([1, (3,1,1,1)], [(3,1,1,2), (5,)])[flush][straight]
    return score, ranks

 >>> poker(['8C TS KC 9H 4S', '7D 2S 5D 3S AC', '8C AD 8D AC 9C', '7C 5H 8D TD KS'])
 '8C AD 8D AC 9C'
```

Comment: which line throws this?

Comment: winner = sorted(scores , key=lambda x:x[1])[-1][0]

Answer (score 5):

It is happening because you are comparing `int` and a `tuple`. In python2x, default `cmp` operation was defined for different inbuilt objects, which has been removed in python3.

> Python 3 ignores the **cmp**() method. In addition to this, the cmp() function is gone! This typically results in your converted code raising a TypeError: unorderable types error. So you need to replace the **cmp**() method with rich comparison methods instead. To support sorting you only need to implement **lt**(), the method used for the “less then” operator, <.

[Official documentation](http://python3porting.com/problems.html#comparisons)

So, in python2, we can do something like this

```
(2, 3) > 2
```

but it raises `TypeError` in python3. If this code was working in python2, then most probably it was bug that was implicitly being handled by default comparison behaviour.

Now in your example:-

```
#value of scores that are being compared for sorting
scores = [(0, (1, (11, 8, 7, 6, 2))), (1, (1, (12, 5, 3, 1, 0))), (2, ((2, 2, 1), (12, 6, 7))), (3, (1, (11, 8, 6, 5, 3)))]

print(type(scores[1][1][0])) # <class 'int'>
print(type(scores[2][1][0])) # <class 'tuple'>
```

which as I have explained does not work in python3. What is the criteria you are assuming for comparing a `tuple` and an `int`.

If you really want to compare different type of objects, then you need to roll out your own version of `tuple`, and use that object in your `scores` instead.

```
class MyTuple(tuple):

     def __lt__(self, other):
        pass
```

[Default tuple comparison python 2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tuple_cmp.htm)

Note:- I don't recommend using this approach. It was just for instructional purposes.

Comment: I copied to code from another post on stack exchange. I think if it would work it would be very elegant

Comment: Is there a way to invoke Python 2 behaviour for this context?

Comment: If the code wasn't buggy, then default implementation of `cmp` between `int` and `tuple` was working for the programmer who wrote it. In your case, you need to use custom object instead of tuple like `MyTuple` I mentioned and define behavior of default python comparison as I mentioned in my edited post.

Answer (score 2):

The solution:
Convert the integer into a tuple:
score = ([(1, ), (3,1,1,1)], [(3,1,1,2), (5,)])[flush][straight]